# Proving that a set is an orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

Any ideas on how to quickly show that

$$
\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}, \frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{\pi}}, \frac{\sin(2x)}{\sqrt{\pi}}, ..., \frac{\sin(nx)}{\sqrt{\pi}}, \frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{\pi}}, \frac{\cos(2x)}{\sqrt{\pi}}, ..., \frac{\cos(nx)}{\sqrt{\pi}} \right)
$$

is an orthonormal basis of vectors in $C[-\pi, \pi]$ (the vector space of continuos real valued functions on $[-\pi, \pi]$) where the inner product is defined as

$$
\left<f, g\right> = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)g(x) \, dx
$$

I found some integration formulae that allow you to show it but I don't really want to have to re-derive all of them on my homework. I'm wondering if there's a simpler argument that you can make.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: We'll I found a list of horribly ugly integrals for functions like $\sin(mx)\cos(nx)$. Running through them for $m \neq n$ shows that they're orthogonal, I'm just looking for a more elegant way.

Comment: What do you know about $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}h(x)dx$ where h(x) has period $2\pi$?  What about period $\pi$?  What about the product of two such functions? Figure this out and you won't need any list of integrals.

Comment: http://www.sosmath.com/trig/prodform/prodform.html. You will definitely need these formulas.

Comment: The ugly integrals for functions like $\sin(mx)\cos(nx)$ is the standard way to prove this fact.  (It is proved in every introductory book on Fourier series.)

Answer (score 2):

To handle the product of trig functions with $n\ne m$, you can [integrate by parts twice](http://calculus7.org/2013/10/31/integrate-by-parts-twice-and-solve-for-the-integral/), ending up with the same integral multiplied by $n^2/m^2$. Boundary terms disappear because of periodicity.

The above is a more conceptual proof than messing with product-sum formulas, because it uses what is really   essential here: the basis is formed by eigenfunctions of a symmetric operator.

The above does not work for $\cos nx \sin nx$, and for a good reason: two eigenfunctions with the *same* eigenvalue have no need to be orthogonal. These two happen to be orthogonal due to  our convenient definition  of trigonometric functions. Simple reason: the product is odd, and the interval of integration is symmetric.